# Flags are broken on MSO

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, flags

[image: Broken flags]

Something seems to be wrong with flags on MSO. Everywhere I look at the results of flags they're not there, the counts seem to be wrong and Community has gone nuts on the "more than 20 comments" flags that are being raised.

Comment: Shhh, if we don't say anything maybe they'll leak *more* code later on!

Comment: I guess that explains why they're lower case though :)

Comment: I laughed: http://i.stack.imgur.com/GazXE.png

Comment: Why, the BLAZES, are they lower-casing flag responses?!  Judicious use of cApS makes text so much easier to rEaD.

Comment: Also, my flag count is way lower than it used to be.

Comment: Yeah, I lost about 60 of 80 flags.

Comment: @mikeTheLiar ARE YOU LYING? Looking into it :)

Comment: @JarrodDixon I've lost quite a few flags too. I have the deputy badge, but my flag page only shows 15..

Comment: @Seth It's a known issue... any "recommend closure" flags aren't being shown right now.  Working on it.

Comment: @Jarrod Oh, so *I'm* suspicious, but Evil Bender is believable? Bah! You sicken me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sure enough, we missed a few parenthisisiisisisses.  It should be fixed now.

Comment: Not sure it's completely fixed. The formatting is still a little... strange: http://i.stack.imgur.com/a61qs.png

Comment: My helpful flag count is still lower than it was yesterday (8 -> 3).

Comment: Mine's down from 180ish to 8.  I'm going to hope it's caching :D -- although it's mainly VTC flags from before I had votes so it's probably related to the close vote changes?

Comment: It's still missing the text from the actual flag on my profile. (I.e. the bit that says NAA or VLQ etc.)

Comment: I'm still missing quite a few flags and none at all are showing when I try to view them.

Comment: ...and they're back :)

Comment: @Geoff Looks like still you missed a few parenthisisiisisisses