# Close votes are counting as flags (again)

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, flags

Questions that have been deleted, which I voted to close in addition to flagging, are showing my close votes as if they were flags on MSO.

For instance [this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/178219/what-is-the-best-way-to-tour-china-if-you-dont-speak-the-language)

> [image]

and [this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182238/how-to-block-porn-on-a-smartphone)

> [image]

Answers which I've flagged as spam don't show this...

The same was [sort of](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/flags-are-broken-on-mso/184187#comment562710_184187) [showing yesterday](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a61qs.png) when things were broken but without the close reason.

---

This is now broken again, save on Stack Overflow not MSO:

> [image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

We moved close votes into the same table that flags reside in (close votes are essentially another form of content flagging) and the close votes were slipping through here.

It is now fixed.

Comment: This seems to have happened on SO now...

Comment: Ah, is that why I suddenly and most unexpectedly got the Marshall badge.

Comment: @MartinSmith you received the badge because we're now properly counting comment flags - so thank you for the flagging :)

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards hmm, I'm not seeing it happening on your profile - do you have a specific instance where it is?

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16830286/check-if-a-column-has-a-defined-set-of-characters) is the one I added to the question but I've just noticed it happened [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17235244/why-distinct-is-not-working-at-this-sql-query-complex-query-duplicate) as well... @Jarrod.

Comment: @benisuǝqbackwards Ah, the "not constructive" is a comment flag - that page needs to have some work done on it to make the different flag types more distinguished.

Comment: Oops @Jarrod, sorry about the nagging then :-)! Yes please... it's not at all clear. It must have been a snarky comment that I didn't want to flag as offensive.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!