# MSO votes activity tab doesn't show closure and reopen votes sub-tabs

Tags: support, status-completed, vote-to-close, meta, recent-activity

MSO votes activity tab in my profile doesn't show closure and reopen votes sub-tabs. Is that OK?

For comparison, votes tab in my SO profile shows mentioned sub-tabs. Comparison screen shot is below.

> [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8wJXe.png]

Comment: Presumably this is because [they're no longer "votes"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184338/close-votes-are-counting-as-flags/185494#185494), but it'd be nice if they still had tabs there.

Comment: @TimStone - Pretty much the reason (that and some hairy code paths that need some work).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

look!

closure and reopen are back, as if they never went away.

Let me know if you find any bugs there.

Comment: All the votes are listed as "undovote", and have the wrong timestamp, but otherwise it looks good ;)

Comment: Also expired votes should be marked as such, under the action name, if we're aiming to be consistent with the original implementation.

Comment: @TimStone - How does it look now?

Comment: The timestamps are still wrong, but otherwise it looks good (although "closure" is inconsistently coloured as maroon, but it looks like that's intentional?)

Comment: Whoops, scratch the bit about the inconsistency, I was only comparing between the two tabs and failed to see that "delete" and "closure" were indeed consistent. So, only the timestmaps.

Comment: @TimStone - Give it 5 for the timestamp issue.

Comment: all votes in my activity -> closure sub tab say "(deleted)", even those where clicking the question link clearly shows me among those who closed it. But anyway, that's quite a relief to see them back!

Comment: @gnat - do you mean under `votes` -> `closure`? There is no `activity` -> `closure` on Meta.

Comment: @gnat - I think the `(deleted)` means that they have aged (not sure, though), something new.

Comment: @Oded yes, votes->closure. "(deleted)" means just this - aged votes, in my experience it was also shown in cases of reopen. Thing is though, it doesn't look like applicable in some examples I've seen. Eg [this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173762): my vote was cast on Jun 21, question has been closed the same day, 338 views since March suggest it wasn't highly viewed, not enough to age my vote; and, well, I am listed among close voters there, and it's not reopened

Comment: @Oded per my observation upon CVs cast during last 3 hours, "(deleted)" in MSO closures sub-tab isn't displayed only for questions that aren't yet closed. That certainly differs from the way it is in my profile pages at Programmers and SO

Comment: @gnat - OK. I have an idea about the cause. Need to figure out a good solution though.

Comment: @Oded I just discovered a detailed explanation of that _deleted_ - [What causes close votes to be annotated with “(deleted)”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175611/165773) Per my reading it's an accepted bug / status-by-design (meaning apparently will-not-fix). To avoid misunderstanding, I don't complain, merely point this for the record. I think I got used to that bug :)