# Saw two "not constructive" flags

Tags: support, declined-flags, comment-flags

I saw two "declined" flags I'm supposed to have cast on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138019/is-this-a-good-login-system-can-i-improve-it).

[image]

I do, however, remember being sympathetic with the OP and it would seem odd that I cast two such flags. Also shouldn't those be *votes* rather than flags? Also I wonder about the quick succession.

Could anybody with the access and a minute to spare satisfy my curiosity and tell me what happened here?

(Totally low priority, I am probably just not remembering what I did back then and everything's perfectly normal.)

Comment: The post flag history says these are comment flags.

Comment: Jarrod mentions that the post needs to have some work done on it to distinguish between close flags and comment flags... It seems like if you have over 3k assume they're comments for the time being.

Comment: [current dupe](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184338/close-votes-are-counting-as-flags-again) is wrong, it's a duplicate of [More informative flagging history for comments](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180377/more-informative-flagging-history-for-comments)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flag history has started to surface comment flags. I've noticed this for the past, oh, week or two. You might notice that the total flag count shown on your user page has increased to include (presumably) all of your comment flags since the beginning of time.

Comment: This change was pushed along with the new close reasons.

Comment: Ahhh, this makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: @animuson: Was this posted somewhere? I couldn't find a feature-request or announcement when I looked the other day.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: It wasn't announced. I had noticed [in another bug report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184233/helpful-flag-count-and-flagging-history-shows-wrong-details/184275#comment563158_184275) where it got confirmed.

Comment: Got it, thanks, @animuson.