# Close vote review queue wording is clunky

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, wording

[image]

I know that close votes are technically flags now, but this wording seems a little forced. Can we change it back to how it was, or at least to "this question has been flagged *as*" ?

Comment: "close votes are technically flags now" - They are? Since when?

Comment: @Doorknob [Since June 2013](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185494/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, that is definitely some awkward wording. I've changed it to read as follows:

> This question has been flagged as:

This will be live in the next build (meta: > `rev  2014.10.16.2667`, q&a: > `rev 2014.10.16.1945`).