# Spam and offensive flags are not counted as helpful flags

Tags: bug, status-completed, spam, flag-history, offensive

Yesterday, the [flags are broken on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184176/flags-are-broken-on-mso) and [wrong details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184233/helpful-flag-count-and-flagging-history-shows-wrong-details) are shown on both flagging history and flags count.

That issue got solved, the flagging history is now seems fine. But, the helpful flag count only includes moderator attention flags. It doesn't count the spam and offensive flags.

See my profile showing helpful flag count as 158,

> [image]

and see my flagging history,

[image]

The helpful flag count does not include the spam and offensive flags in the new build.

Comment: Looks like counting condition is working reverse from yesterday's count. Yesterday It was counting only Spam & Offensive flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The numbers for moderator attention flags *included* spam, offensive and comment flags, where they shouldn't have.

This has been corrected and will be in the next build.

Comment: I am not getting what's going on with flags. I had more than 40 helpful comment flags (I have flagged more that 50 comments) But at present it shows only 13 flagged comment and 11 helpful. Also Stack Overflow flagging summery seems correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: @hims056 - we do have an issue with comment flags. Working on it.

Comment: Okay thanks for your confirmation.

Comment: Looks like it is fixed. :)