# Suddenly increased number of flags remaining in MSO & SO

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, flags, meta

Recently there are a few changes in Flagging term on meta site. Due to this there was some flag counting problem in profile's helpful flag. Now it looks [solved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184405/173001).  But just now when I click on the flag link, I found that there is increase of number in flag a post, have a look at following image,

> [image]

As you can see Now I can flag maximum 61 post ( I have already used one, so it's showing 60 in image ).

This change has come suddenly So, I think this is again due to that flag changes problem, because till I remember I was having flag count around 40 something.

It shows same count for Spam & Offensive flag also.

### Edit

Now It looks that this new flag weight system has been applied in Stack Overflow too, I just logged it and found that my flag weight is being increased from 46 to 100 (yesterday night it was 46), see the following images,

> [image]

Even Spam & Offensive flag weight is also increase and lost it's red color.

> [image]

Kindly look into this and fix it.

Comment: Non repro for me, having my usual 31 flags. Maybe they changed the flag weight algorithm?

Comment: Well My colleague's flag weight changed, after confirming this, I post this question. How come it is not showing change in your flag weight ?

Comment: Flag weight is hidden, all we see is how many flags we have remaining for the day. Hopefully a dev will pop soon and explain everything. :-)

Comment: Of course it is hidden to other users, but I can see my colleague's flag weight, as he is sitting next to me.

Comment: Nope, maybe you mean helpful flags count. Flag weight is something that used to be public and calculated *based* on the helpful/declined flags and it determines (to this day) how many total flags one have. [See here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/119715/152859).

Comment: No I did't mean helpful flag count. Just click to any post and see, how many flag count it shows for you for a single day. I mean the same dialogbox as I post in Question.

Comment: Flag count != flag weight. :-)

Comment: Bon Appetite! ;)

Comment: `if (user.DisplayName == 'Lucifer') flags.Remaining += 60;`

Comment: @TimPost in that case it will increase each 'Lucifer''s flag weight :P

Comment: I got a big increase myself (so far on Au only). From 45 to 99.

Comment: me too got big increment from 46 to 100, more than double.

Comment: On the contrary, my flag count decreased from 37 to 25.

Comment: may be more of your flags got declined, so resultan your flag ability got decreased.

Comment: Nope. I didn't flag anything yesterday. All it takes is just one day and the flag count decreases by 12.

Comment: @Antony, I think its not because of only yesterday's result, It may be because of your few declined flags in recent days. I too lost flag weight from 21 to 12 on Super user because few of my flag got declined, but on the other hand on SO I got increment in flag weight because only 4-5 flags were declined recently while I have raised more that 1500 helpful flags recently by daily's flag queue handling.

Comment: I had 37 flags yesterday and I have 25 today. I only have 1 declined flag that was 4 months ago. What gives?

Comment: @Shog9 So what does it mean when my flag count decreased?

Comment: I honestly have no idea, @Antony.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number-of-flags algorithm just got changed. See Shog9's answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/215468).

Here's the fundamentals of his answer reproduced here:

> - you start with 10 flags per day.
> - 100 flags per day max - that's 100 comment flags and 100 post flags (including spam, offensive, and close)
> - extra flag for every 2000 reputation
> - extra flag for every 10 net helpful flags (helpful-unhelpful).

The change you're observing (and which Shog can't be bothered to find a proper reference for right now) is likely the collapsing of flag types into one big "post flags" bucket. This means those 100 flags have to cover any spam, close, not an answer, etc. flagging needs during the course of a day - you can't burn 100 spam flags and then start in on non-answers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/flag-posts

Comment: @Lucifer Shog9 > privs page.

Comment: @Lucifer Or are you saying I should update it?

Comment: I am saying that, your answer's contain is already there in that flag-post's link at the end of that page. But since there is some changes in new flag system that's why there is an increment of flag weight. [see this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184187/173001)

Comment: So that's why my count went down....

Answer (score 0):

Besides what [Undo said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185907/203389), [Jarrod Dixon said](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/185866/flag-count-is-missing-from-profile-pages/185889#comment570008_185889) that the increase was also caused by corrections in the way comment flags were counted.

[image]