# Suddenly decreased number of flags remaining on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, review, flags

While some others have [an increased number of flags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184683/suddenly-increased-number-of-flags-remaining-in-mso-so) after a recent change, the number of flags I have decreased from 37 to 25.

> [image: flag remaining decreased]

I had 37 flags yesterday but 25 today. I just had a helpful flag yesterday and I didn't flag anything more for the whole week. I only have 1 declined flag that was 4 months ago. What happened?

> [image]

(That disputed flag was once marked as none before because I [voted to close a question after I have flagged it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120825/voting-close-on-a-question-you-flagged-marks-your-flag-as-none) as I transitioned to 3k. It suddenly becomes disputed today.)

Comment: @Lucifer What does it have to do with review?

Comment: Actually I found it doing `review` so I added that tag, later on I reliaze that there was no meaning of adding it. However keeping it is also a meaning.

Comment: @Lucifer I find it hard to understand your line of thought. That's kind of philosophical.

Comment: ok, let me explain, you are not 10K use so you are not reviewing the `flag queue review` section. You found flag weight decrement as you just flag a post, while I found it when I was handling a flag from `flag review` queue so I added it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The algorithm [has changed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185890/152859):

> - You start with 10 flags per day.
> - You get an extra flag per day for every 2000 reputation points or 10 net helpful flags (helpful-unhelpful).
> - You can end up with as many as 100 per day

So you start with 10, plus 2 due to reputation that's 12.

129 + 6 + 2 + 3 - 1 = 139 so that's 13 flags more, totalling in 25.

The old algorithm used to calculate the amount of daily flags can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80117/152859). Mirror:

> - default 10 per day
> - one bonus flag per 2000 reputation
> - one bonus flag per 20 "flag weight" above the default
> - maximum 100

And flag weight algorithm:

> - start at 100
> - +10 for a flagged post (+5 for a comment) that we did something about (or was basically valid)
> - -10 for a flagged post (-5 for a comment) that we suppressed as invalid
> - min 0, max 750 (but non-linear above 500)

Comment: Where can I find the old algorithm then?

Comment: Was looking for it, have to go now but will keep looking later if nobody will find it before. :)

Comment: @Antony OK, found it. Too complex to calculate, feel free to do that yourself. :-)

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Thanks.

Comment: Somehow I missed this change until looking for it right now.  Was the rationale for dropping the flag weight statistic a performance thing?  Or a feature removal?

Comment: @Garry the flag weight was more like a game to many users who were racing to increase it. Not sure how harmful it was, maybe the team thought it's better if people will spend more time posting and voting not just flagging.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd, thanks for the explanation.  I really liked that feature and it's a shame if people were abusing it.